# How would I implement the Matlab skeletonizing/thinning algorithm on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, matlab, image-processing

How can I implement the Matlab algorithm that will skeletonize / thin binary (black
and white) images in Objective-C within an iPhone app?

Comment: Would be great if you could tell us how the Matlab algorithm works... I just found bwmorph() which should do just the same as the way I provided below. Implement 8 little 3x3 matrices for the operators hardcode them into your routune and "slide" them over each pixel of your image (two loops for x and y direction). On each pixel you use the operators to see whether you can erode something by comparing the corresponding pixels of the image and your operator. If you put a while(true) loop around the everything it will then go over the pixels and erode and erode til you have your skeleton left.

Answer (score 4):

Well basically you could use morpholocial operators for this...

Build eight hit-or-miss operators like this:

```
      0 0 0
St1 = x 1 x  (for deleting upper pixels)
      1 1 1
```

rotate this 4 times to get it for the 4 sides. Then also build 4 more ofr the corners like this:

```
      0 0 x
St5 = 0 1 1   (rotate this again 4 times for the 4 corners)
      x 1 1
```

Then you erode your image (with loops) until none of the operators can be used anymore... what is left is the skeleton of that image...

This shouldn't be too hard to implement in Objective C I guess... (not familiar with it) ... this is a general strategy...

Hope that helps... if not, keep asking... ;-)

Comment: what do u mean by erode your images with loops?

Comment: With loops I mean that you simply convolute each of the operators over the image again and again... This will detele pixels on the outside. If you do it like that you can maintain a small skeleton line... Erosion itsel is described here as well: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/erode.htm

Maybe that helps...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I've wrote GLSL fragment shader which performs fast skeletonization on images. You can apply this shader in a loop until you get what you need. GLSL shader code:

```
uniform sampler2D Texture0;
varying vec2 texCoord;

// 3x3 pixel window
// (-1,+1) (0,+1) (+1,+1)
// (-1,0)  (0,0)  (+1,0)
// (-1,-1) (0,-1) (+1,-1)

float dtex = 1.0 / float(textureSize(Texture0,0));  

vec4 pixel(int dx, int dy) { 
   return texture2D(Texture0,texCoord + 
                    vec2(float(dx)*dtex, float(dy)*dtex));
}

int exists(int dx, int dy) {
   return int(pixel(dx,dy).r < 0.5);
}

int neighbors() {
   return  exists(-1,+1) +
           exists(0,+1) +
           exists(+1,+1) +
           exists(-1,0) +
           exists(+1,0) +
           exists(-1,-1) +
           exists(0,-1) +
           exists(+1,-1);
}

int transitions() {
   return int(
          clamp(float(exists(-1,+1))-float(exists(0,+1)),0.,1.) +  // (-1,+1) -> (0,+1)
          clamp(float(exists(0,+1))-float(exists(+1,+1)),0.,1.) +  // (0,+1) -> (+1,+1)
          clamp(float(exists(+1,+1))-float(exists(+1,0)),0.,1.) +  // (+1,+1) -> (+1,0)
          clamp(float(exists(+1,0))-float(exists(+1,-1)),0.,1.) +  // (+1,0) -> (+1,-1)
          clamp(float(exists(+1,-1))-float(exists(0,-1)),0.,1.) +  // (+1,-1) -> (0,-1)
          clamp(float(exists(0,-1))-float(exists(-1,-1)),0.,1.) +  // (0,-1) -> (-1,-1)
          clamp(float(exists(-1,-1))-float(exists(-1,0)),0.,1.) +  // (-1,-1) -> (-1,0)
          clamp(float(exists(-1,0))-float(exists(-1,+1)),0.,1.)    // (-1,0) -> (-1,+1)          
          );
}

int MarkedForRemoval() {
   int neib = neighbors();
   int tran = transitions();

   if (exists(0,0)==0  // do not remove if already white
       || neib==0      // do not remove an isolated point
       || neib==1      // do not remove tip of a line
       || neib==7      // do not remove located in concavity
       || neib==8      // do not remove not a boundary point
       || tran>=2      // do not remove on a bridge connecting two or more edge pieces
       )
       return 0;
   else
      return 1;
}

void main(void)
{
    int remove = MarkedForRemoval();
    vec4 curr = texture2D(Texture0,texCoord);
    vec4 col = vec4(remove,remove,remove,1.0);
    gl_FragColor = (remove==1)? col:((curr.r > 0.05)? 
                                     vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0):curr);
}
```

Only this time code is based on [this lecture](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/morphology/node2.html) (actually on first part of lecture, so algorithm has some bugs :-) ) 
See what happens when poor chimpanzee was constantly fed with this GLSL shader:

Iteration 0
[image]

Iteration 5
[image]

Iteration 10
[image]

Iteration 15
[image]

Comment: I tried to convert colored image to binary image in .m file with a function and how can I use fragment shader with method in this class? I didnt use opengl before.can u help me?

Comment: Here I found tutorial xcode iPad/GLSL project with shaders-
https://github.com/turner/HelloiPadGLSL
There should be other glsl tutorials on net also...
On the other hand you don't necessary need pixel shaders to implement skeletonization algorithm on iPhone. Simply assume that shader program void main(void)
{gl_FragColor = ...
}
returns color for the current pixel. So you can write something like:
For each pixel in Image:
  Apply_New_Pixel_Color().
Hope that helps.