# How to find the centerline line of 2-dimensional long region

Tags: algorithm, matlab, graphics, geometry, 2d

How to design a thinning algorithm to find the center-line of a 2-dimensional long region, for instance a river in a geological map? or is there any other method to find the center-line of an irregular 2-dimensional long region?

Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: What do you mean by irregular 2D strip?

Comment: Do you mean: two polylines kind of parallel to each other along their length, separated from each other by a more-or-less constant distance?

Comment: @Jean:  sometimes it could be wide, and sometimes it could be narrow

Comment: @Bret: I mean 2-dimensional long region, for instance a river in a geological map.

Comment: How are the edges of the river defined? Are they polylines? Mathematical expressions? Pixels?

Comment: Yes, they are defined by pixels.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809523/how-would-i-implement-the-matlab-skeletonizing-thinning-algorithm-on-the-iphone

Comment: IPT has a function for that for that (skeletonization): http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwmorph.html

Comment: And this question should be closed why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to search for "Skeletonization". Roughly it's extraction of center lines from graphical objects. There are several algorithms for this:

1. gradually remove pixels which are not part of skeleton: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/projects97/azar/skeleton.html#define
2. sending wave from object borders to inside and looking for self-collisions
3. sending wave from some part of the object and looking for middle of wave front

Answer (score 1):

[I made it a separate answer, because approach is too different]

This approach is applicable for rivers without branches:

1. Extract "left" and "right" border as sequences of pixel coordinates
2. Find correspondence between pixels from left and right borders (e.g. with dynamic programming)
3. Define centre line points as middle points between two corresponding left and right points

Edit:

By correspondence I mean sequence of pairs of pixels  which goes continuously along both borders keeping distance between them minimal. "Continuously" means that we either do one step along both borders or one step along one of them.

Example of finding such sequence is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: How do you define "correspondence"?

Comment: This marching algorithm can get stuck if there is an "asperity" in one of the borders, can't it?

Comment: **as·per·i·ty** *|əˈsperədē|* : harshness of tone or manner.